# How to dump remote SQL Server 2005 database schema?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want to get the schema of tables from a remote database. I only have the username and password of remote SQL Server. It doesn't provide any tools like in SQL Server Management Studio. What is the proper way for getting schema of tables from this remote sql server? please help

Comment: If you have a username and password, why can't you use your own copy of Management Studio to connect (and use things like Generate Scripts)?

Comment: yes but I dont have management studio. is ther any  other way ? @ Aaron Bertrand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 2012 SP1 version of Management Studio Express is fully functional and free. [Go download it](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35579) instead of trying to reinvent the wheel.